# What technologies are used for WYSIWYG layout/design/personalized webpage apps?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm trying to figure out the different skills and technologies necessary to develop webpage personalization apps that allow users to input and edit text/images/links on a webpage. About.me and Flavors.me would be the most advanced examples of what I'm talking about. Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

@tim, they're database driven apps.  The user enters information into a database (or Facebook profile, etc) and it's then pulled back out via a scripting language and presented on the page.  The page layout is also stored in a DB and brought together with the user's profile information for what becomes the page layout you see.  About.me seems to take it a step further by creating an email account that's tied to the user account.

Technology-wise, just about any back-end language could be used.  Facebook is written in PHP, though they have a language-agnostic API that could be talked to from .net, java, php, etc.  You'll need a database, and that probably would either be MySQL, Sql Server or Postgres, though there are certainly others.  Finally you'd probably want to make use of the API's I spoke about including Facebook, Google, LinkedIn, etc. to aggregate information the user already has entered in different locations.

Examples of this type of site are varied and all over.  Mint.com does it for financials.  Grooveshark will tie into facebook and others to communicate and share your music collection.  Linked in will tie into others as well.  Integration is actually a very lucrative segment of the programming business right now.  An app that talks to others has good marketable value.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I guess where I get a little confused is where server side ends and client side begins with interfaces like these? Ie, the actual gui I use to input text or change the font size/color. Very beginner kind of question, I know. Appreciate the help.

Comment: That's really up to you.  I separate my UI from the application layer.  So, my interfaces will most often populate via AJAX, interact via Jquery, then save via AJAX to a php script.  From there, it does the database interactions, server side validation, etc.  It returns via the AJAX success, then "does stuff" such as modal windows, highlighting, populating, etc for user feedback.  And the circle continues over and over, garbage in, garbage out.